# In MySQL, How do I Select the Column in a Row with the Highest Value

Tags: mysql

I have a customer price/rates table that probably could have been more normalized, but 10 years in, it is what it is. For brevity's sake, here are the relevant columns:

```
id
client_id
service_1_rate
service_2_rate
[. . .]
service_10_rate
```

I need to know, for each column, what is the highest rate I am charging that particular client.

This is not a MAX() scenario - I am not trying to find which row has the maximum value in a particular column - I am trying to find out, for each row, which column in that row has the highest value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [`greatest()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to get the highest service rate:

```
select id, client_id, 
  greatest(service_1_rate, service_2_rate, . . ., service_10_rate) highest
from tablename
```

If you want the *index* of the column with the highest rating you can also use the function [`field()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
select id, client_id, 
  field(
    greatest(service_1_rate, service_2_rate, . . ., service_10_rate), 
    service_1_rate, service_2_rate, . . ., service_10_rate
  ) highest
from tablename
```

Or if you want the name of the column with the highest rate you can use a `CASE` espression:

```
select id, client_id, 
  case greatest(service_1_rate, service_2_rate, . . ., service_10_rate) 
    when service_1_rate then 'service_1_rate'
    when service_2_rate then 'service_2_rate' 
    .........................................
  end highest
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

For inspecting a single row, we could use the `GREATEST` function to return the highest value. A demonstration with literals:

```
SELECT GREATEST( 2 , 3 , 42 , 5 , 7 ) AS highest_val
```

We can use column names (or other expressions) in place of the literals; if any of the expressions are NULL, the function will return NULL.

But that only evaluates the *value*, doesn't tell us which expression in the list supplied that value. We can search a list of expressions for a matching value, and return the position in the list.  (If multiple expressions have the same highest value, the position of the first one encountered is returned, e.g.

```
SELECT FIELD( GREATEST( 2 , 3 , 42 , 42 , 7 ), 2 , 3 , 42 , 42 , 7 ) AS which_is_highest
```

We could translate that position into a string, using `ELT` function. As an example:

```
SELECT ELT(3, 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth' )
```

---

Putting all that together...

For brevity sake, let's assume we are needing to evaluate six columns r1, r2, r3, r4, r5 and r6. Let's also assume that columns can't (or won't) ever contain NULL values.

To get the one highest value from the six columns :

```
 SELECT ...
      , GREATEST(t.r1,t.r2,t.r3,t.r4,t.r5,t.r6)  AS highest_val
   FROM t
  ORDER BY ...
```

To get the name of the column that returned the highest value :

```
SELECT ...
     , ELT(
         FIELD(
           GREATEST(t.r1,t.r2,t.r3,t.r4,t.r5,t.r6)
         ,t.r1,t.r2,t.r3,t.r4,t.r5,t.r6)
       ,'r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6')          AS col_with_highest_val
     , ...
  FROM t
```